# Javascript displaying only one row(recordset) instead of multiple rows

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, recordset

I am trying to display the whole table of rows which comes from the recordset, but instead it display only one record. Please help. I know i am missing something, but not sure what.

Thanks in advance

```
    Do Until rs.eof = True
    response.write("<tr id='testable' style='display:none;'>")
    response.write("<td width='10%' align='left'>")
    response.write(rs(0))
    response.write("</td>")
    response.write("<td>")
    response.write(rs(1))
    response.write("</td>")
    response.write("</tr>")
    response.write(vbcrlf)
    rs.MoveNext
    response.write(vbcrlf) 
    Loop
```

```js
    var x = document.getElementById("testable");
        if (x.style.display == "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } 
        else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
```

Display Now:

```
 123 abc
```

Display want:

```
123 abc
456 pqr
789 xyz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every new row that you write has it's `display:none` and has the same `id`.

When this JavaScript runs: `document.getElementById("testable");`, only the first element with that `id` is found  and so only the first element has its `display` altered to `show`.

**ID's must be unique within a web page** so don't give each new row the same one. Instead, consider giving them all the same `class` (which is allowed). Then, your JavaScript could loop through all of them and change their `display` like this:

```
// Assume that each <tr> has a class of row

let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");

rows.forEach(function(row){
  row.style.display = (row.style.display = "hidden") ? "block" : "hidden";
});
```

Comment: thank you Sir, have to edit the rest of the code accordingly. but solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

To extend upon @Scott Marcus's answer. On top of using classes consider adding the result ID's to your TR IDs to make them unique.

```
response.write("<tr id='testable-" & rs(0) & "' style='display:none;'>")
```

This will help if you only want to make one row visible at a time and be able to toggle each individually, and if you want to show/hide them all at once you can do it with jquery:

```
$("tr[id*='testable-']").hide();
$("tr[id*='testable-']").show();
```

You can read more about hide here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_hide.asp

Comment: Actually, this isn't a good idea. Moving completely away from ID's is the best approach. ID's make solutions more brittle (as this question shows). Additionally, they make for more specific CSS selectors, which are harder to override when needed (again more brittle).

Comment: You could add selectors that target all rows with IDs starting with testable- using jquery to get the same job done. Example: $("tr[id*='testable-']")  | This way you can have both a specific row selector and target all of them depending on your need.

Comment: Yes, but the point is to not have a specific selector. You'll find that keeping things non-specific creates the most flexible solutions. As you can see in my answer, having all the rows have a simple `row` class, solves the problem quite easily.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my intention. I don't think your solution is wrong or bad, but being able to just hide/show one of the rows could be a real use case and then using only classes will be hard. My solution offers the ability of hiding/showing a single row or everything at once using jquery (editing in the jquery to the answer to make it more clear). Either way, there are more than one way to solve this problem. In the end it's down to the user how they are comfortable coding it. I prefer ID selectors in this type of scenario.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative. I do understand what you're saying. I don't think you fully understand what I'm saying. Even if you do want to affect a single row, there are many ways to access it uniquely without it having an `id` and they are not hard, as you say. Yes, working with `id`s is perfectly legitimate, but their use more often than not leads to code that doesn't scale and has to be re-worked when it does scale (as all applications tend to do over time). Avoiding the more specific coding patterns is always a good software design practice (i.e. loose coupling).

Comment: For the sake of argument (pun intended :) ), or rather because I'm genuinely interested how I can make my coding habits better. How would you handle individual showing and hiding of rows if not by using IDs? I'm working with a lot of tabled divs and showing/hiding, highlighting and processing a lot of individual data for each entry and setting IDs based on their database ids have been my solution to it. That way I know that if I target a div or span, I know which database entry it belongs to based on that. Do you have any tips on what could work better, and especially be more future-proof?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this issue, so without knowing your exact scenario, it's hard to say which is best, but you could attach `data-*` attributes to your HTML elements that can then be used to filter for just the right one(s), you could use the CSS `nth-child`, `nth-of-type`, `first-child`, `last-child` selectors. You could use CSS classes and or combination of element/sectors/positions. There are literally dozens of combinations of these techniques that can be used, all of which do not require `id`s.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to read up more on the `data-*` attribute. Seems interesting and quite flexible!